# SonarQube not reachable on 127.0.0.1:9000 under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, sonarqube

I want to run SonarQube on my Ubuntu 18.04 server along with nginx (a Droplet at DigitalOcean).

Mostly I've followed these [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-ensure-code-quality-with-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-18-04). I've used Postgres instead of MySQL.

Nginx should accept the request and pass it to the localhost-address used by SonarQube (127.0.0.1:9000).

Nginx is running and working. SSL is active and working. Here my codequality.example.com.conf:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name codequality.example.com www.codequality.example.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/codequality.example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/codequality.example.com.error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/codequality.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/codequality.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    }
}
```

The command `systemctl status sonarqube` gives me the following response:

> ● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-17 22:16:50 UTC; 5s ago
>     Process: 21796 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>     Process: 21855 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    Main PID: 21918 (wrapper)
>       Tasks: 43 (limit: 2361)
>      CGroup: /system.slice/sonarqube.service
>              ├─21918 /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/../../conf/wrapper.co
>              ├─21922 java -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m -Xmx32m -Djava.library.path=./lib -cl
>              └─21954 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyF
>   lines 1-11/11 (END)

So I can assume that SonarQube-Server is running correctly. Trying to access SonarQube via https://codequality.example.com results in a 502 Error. The log-file says:

> 2020/03/17 22:19:44 [error] 19598#19598: *233 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 79.254.63.100, server: codequality.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "codequality.example.com"

Trying to access the localhost (127.0.0.1:9000) during a ssh-session via `curl http://127.0.0.1:9000` I get the error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9000: Connection refused

This is the log from SonarQube:

> 2020.03.17 22:38:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
>   2020.03.17 22:38:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
>   2020.03.17 22:38:54 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
>   2020.03.17 22:38:54 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
>   2020.03.17 22:38:55 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>   2020.03.17 22:38:55 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>   ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
>   [1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-ensure-code-quality-with-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-18-04): max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
>   [2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
>   2020.03.17 22:39:11 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
>   2020.03.17 22:39:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
>   2020.03.17 22:39:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
>   <-- Wrapper Stopped
>   --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
>   Launching a JVM...
>   Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
>     Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is not the NGINX Proxy. The logfile you shared gives some insides

`max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535] [2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144] 2020.03.17 22:39:11 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78 2020.03.17 22:39:11 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped`

Your SonarQube isn't running correctly because of some misconfiguration of elastic sarch.

Check this links to find out how to adjust the limit:

### general information

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html

### how to chnage the settings

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/setting-system-settings.html

Make sure SonarQube is running correctly on localhost:9000 before move on to the proxy configuration.